# $,get method not reading new data after PHP update

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm a calling PHP function which updates a text file with new content. Later on I use AJAX to open the file and read the data after the update, and then call the same function to update the file.

However, the `$.get` method is not reading the new data. For some reason it reads the old data, even after I've refreshed the system a couple of times.

I have checked and the file does contain the new updated data.

How is this possible, and how can I just get the new data that is in the file every time?

```js
$.get(fileName, function(data) {
  analysisVar.stepArray = JSON.parse(data);
  // Do something with the content and then update the file with new content
  updateFile();
});

updateFile() {
  $.post('questions/updateNewStepsToFile.php', {
    "fName": properties["fileName"],
    "newSteps": JSON.stringify(toFile),
  }, function(val) {
    alert(val);
  });
}
```

Comment: Possibly due to caching. Try setting `cache: false`. Also as a side note, be aware that using text files for storage is not a good solution, both in terms of scalability and concurrency. You will quickly have problems if you have even a small number of concurrent users.

Comment: thank you, that worked. is it better to save the data to a database

Comment: Yes, a lot better.